# Catching overflows with boost::lexical_cast

Tags: c++, boost

I want to catch *boost::lexicat_cast* overflows the same way I can catch *boost::numeric_cast* overflows. Is it possible?

The first *try* block below throws a *boost::numeric::negative_overflow*.

The second block does not throw an exception (isn't this a *lexical_cast* bug?)

Though *unsigned int* is used in the example below, I am looking for a method that would work for any integer type.

```
#include <boost/numeric/conversion/cast.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main()
{
    unsigned int i;

    try
    {
        int d =-23;
        i = boost::numeric_cast<unsigned int>(d);
    }
    catch (const boost::numeric::bad_numeric_cast& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << i << std::endl; // 4294967273

    try
    {
        char c[] = "-23";
        i = boost::lexical_cast<unsigned int>(c);
    }
    catch (const boost::bad_lexical_cast& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << i << std::endl; // 4294967273

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not a bug; lexical_cast is deliberately simple, and the documentation recommends you use a stringstream if you need more control. So do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write what you want using a modicum of Spirit:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69e9857e9c961726)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Out, typename In> Out numeric_lexical_cast(In const& range) {

    Out value;

    {
        using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
        using std::begin;
        using std::end;

        if (!parse(begin(range), end(range), auto_ >> eoi, value)) {
            struct bad_numeric_lexical_cast : std::domain_error {
                bad_numeric_lexical_cast() : std::domain_error("bad_numeric_lexical_cast") {}
            };
            throw bad_numeric_lexical_cast();
        }
    }

    return value;
}

int main()
{
    for (std::string const& input : { "23", "-23" }) try {
        std::cout << " == input: " << input << " -> ";
        auto i = numeric_lexical_cast<unsigned int>(input);
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
 == input: 23 -> 23
 == input: -23 -> bad_numeric_lexical_cast
```

Comment: Nice! though it won't work correctly, and won't err for numeric string literals(e.g. numeric_lexical_cast<unsigned int>("123");)

Comment: Just write te necessary overload

Comment: I tried, but failed to write a string literal overload

Comment: Here you go: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/698a179259189407). Note that if you drop `>> eoi` from the parser, you can use `It& f` to detect how much of the input has been parsed.

Comment: I forgot to remove some cruft there, so here's that idea where the check for `eoi` is moved to from the iterator overload to the range/sz overloads. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c39df14fabac6e17